# Replace a string with a pattern found at beginning of line

Tags: string, sed, pattern-matching

I am trying to use `sed` to do this:

I have a file, space-delimited, with 5 columns, as following:

```
45_342 2 SEQUENCE_2 A G
234_43 45 SEQUENCE_45 T G
12_45 9 SEQUENCE_9 C C
1233_456 134 SEQUENCE_134 T A
```

I am trying to replace the string "SEQUENCE" in each line with the pattern found at the beginning of the same line. I should obtain:

```
45_342 2 45_342_2 A G
234_43 45 234_43_45 T G
12_45 9 12_45_9 C C
1233_456 134 1233_456_134 T A
```

I tried to use this logic with the following sed commands:

```
sed -i '/PatternAtBeginnigOfLine/s/SEQUENCE/PatternAtBeginnigOfLine/g' ./file
```

My `sed` code looks like:

```
sed -i '/^[0-9]\+_[0-9]\+\s/s/SEQUENCE/^[0-9]\+_[0-9]\+/g' ./file
```

However I end up with this result

```
45_342 2 ^[0-9]\+_[0-9]\+_2 A G
234_43 45 ^[0-9]\+_[0-9]\+_45 T G
12_45 9 ^[0-9]\+_[0-9]\+_9 C C
1233_456 134 ^[0-9]\+_[0-9]\+_134 T A
```

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you Raju. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

### `sed` solution

```
$ sed -E 's/([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) SEQUENCE/\1 \2 \1/' ./file 
45_342 2 45_342_2 A G
234_43 45 234_43_45 T G
12_45 9 12_45_9 C C
1233_456 134 1233_456_134 T A
```

Or, to change the file in place, add the `-i` option:

```
sed -i -E 's/([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) SEQUENCE/\1 \2 \1/' ./file
```

#### How it works

`s` (substitute) commands are of the form `s/old/new/`.  In our case, the `old` pattern consists of:

```
([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) SEQUENCE
```

Because of the parentheses, this captures the first column in group 1 and the second column in group 2.

The `new` text looks like:

```
\1 \2 \1
```

This means that the matched text is replaced with the first group, denoted `\1`, a space, the second group, denoted `\2`, a space, and the first group again.

Notes:

- I added the `-E` flag which tells `sed` to use extended regular expressions.  This avoids the need for a lot of backslash-escapes.
- Since we want this substitution performed only once on each line, there is no need for the `g` modifier to the substitute command

### `awk` solution

For completeness, here is a solution that uses `awk`:

```
$ awk '{sub("SEQUENCE", $1, $3)} 1' file
45_342 2 45_342_2 A G
234_43 45 234_43_45 T G
12_45 9 12_45_9 C C
1233_456 134 1233_456_134 T A
```

To change the file in-place (assuming that you have a modern GNU awk):

```
awk -i inplace '{sub("SEQUENCE", $1, $3)} 1' file
```

#### How it works

- `sub("SEQUENCE", $1, $3)`

  This looks for `SEQUENCE` in the third field (denoted `$3`).  If it is found, it replaces it with the first field (denoted `$1`).
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-line.

Comment: Oh my god!!!@John1024,  I really appreciate for this unbelievable response. It makes all sense now and I should definitely study the extended regular expressions. You explained it so well it is beautiful. How can I contribute to your thumbs-up?

Comment: By the way, I love SED!

Comment: @PaulL Your welcome.  --- As for StackOverflow's peculiar culture, when you have enough rep, you will be able to vote up answers that you like.  Also, when you decide what answer is best, you can accept it by clicking the large check mark next to it.  For more info, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little Bash script that does it:

```
while read -r col0 col1 col2 rest; do
    printf "%s %s %s %s\n" "$col0" "$col1" "${col2/SEQUENCE/$col0}" "$rest"
done < infile
```

The `while read -r ...; do ... done < infile` loop reads the input file line by line and doesn't interpret backslash sequences (the `-r` flag).

The line is split up using shell [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting), in this case by spaces. The first three fields are assigned to the `col` parameters, and the rest of the line goes into `rest`.

The `printf` line basically prints the same line, but substitutes `SEQUENCE` in the third field by the value of the first field using [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

The result is this:

```
45_342 2 45_342_2 A G
234_43 45 234_43_45 T G
12_45 9 12_45_9 C C
1233_456 134 1233_456_134 T A
```

If you were to time this, the sed and the awk solution, you'd most likely find that sed is faster than this and awk faster than sed.

Answer (score 0):

```
#/tmp$ cat file
45_342 2 SEQUENCE_2 A G
234_43 45 SEQUENCE_45 T G

#/tmp$ sed -r 's/([0-9_]+)(.*)SEQUENCE(.*)/\1\2\1\3/' ./file
45_342 2 45_342_2 A G
234_43 45 234_43_45 T G
```